# Why are the columns of a $3\times 5$ matrix linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a $3 \times 5$ matrix, explain why the columns of $A$ must be linearly dependent?

The Rank Theorem tells me that $rank(A) + nullity(A) = n$ where $n$ represents the total number of variables in the matrix; $nullity(A)$ is the number of free variables in the matrix. The rank of $A$ is the number of pivots or number of linearly independent rows/columns.

Comment: If $A$ is a $3\times 5$ matrix, it doesn't imply the columns are linearly independent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** You have 5 column vectors of $\mathbb R^3$. Thus they can never be linearly independent, because the dimension of $\mathbb R^3$ is 3...

**Longer explanation:** A 3x5 matrix represents a linear map $\mathbb R^5\to \mathbb R^3$. The column vectors of $A$ are the images of the standard basis $e_1,\ldots,e_5$ in $\mathbb R^5$ in $\mathbb R^3$ under A. Thus you have 5 column vectors in the 3-dimensional space $\mathbb R^3$. 5 vectors can never be linearly independent in $\mathbb R^3$...

Comment: What if I had a 4x2 matrix instead and it asked why the rows were linearly dependent? I know it's the same logic but I would be looking at the columns to use for my rank.

Comment: A 4x2 matrix might have linearly independent column vectors...

Answer (score 2):

In general, we have the following fact:

**Fact.** The columns of a $m\times n$ matrix $A$ are linearly dependent if and only if $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(A)=n$.

Since $\rank(A)\leq\min\{m,n\}$ (why?) we see that the columns of an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ are not linearly independent if $m<n$.